# I could run command in terminal but not in crontab (date issue)

Tags: cron, date

I checked many questions like my issue but could not find a solution yet

Following command works without any problem

```
rm -rf <PATH>/<pattern>*$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d "-2 days")*.csv
```

I have edited crontab with like following line

```
39 9  * * * rm -rf <PATH>/<pattern>*$(date +\'\%Y\%m\%d\' -d \"-2 days\")*.csv
```

But I got following error when crond runs my command

```
> date: extra operand `days"'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

I could not find any solution yet, do you have any idea ?

I have tons of file to delete, rm works better than find (-exec rm) command.

Comment: Why did you escape the `'` and `"`?

Comment: I tried many many recommendation and mixed version of recommendation.Now it works without escaping ' and " 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `date -d -2days` (ommit the blank). This should work also without the quoting problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape quotes in crontab. Only `%` is special in most crontabs.